# angular ui-ace production build not working in a jhipster project

Tags: angularjs, jhipster, ui-ace

I have a created a jhipster project

```
  "jhipsterVersion": "4.3.0",
```

I am using this library for a text editor in my project.

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-ace

Everything works super awesome in the dev mode. But when I deploy on prod "ace" cant find its dependent js files.

```
mode-javascript.js
mode-html.js
theme-monokai.js
```

I am not sure how to configure angular ace to get those files on production

THIS IS NOT A JHIPSTER ISSUE, but I am tagging it, hoping someone faced the same issue.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

angular-ace `bower.json` file exposes only ui-ace.js file in its `main` property: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-ace/blob/master/bower.json#L8 but instructions say you must include 3 files.

As JHipster prod build uses bower.json to know which file to inject in index.html, it results in your prod index.html having only ui-ace.js.

Ideally, you should report this to angular-ace author but as this project has not been changed for last 3 years, it's safer to fix it on your side. In fact, it'll be safer to use another project considering all the issues and pull request pending.

To fix it you must edit your app `bower.json` file and add a section for angular-ace to overrides main property and reference the 3 files. There is an example in your project `bower.json` for bootstrap: https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app/blob/master/bower.json#L52-L56

Comment: I was not able to find any other angular lib for code editors, can you recommend a few?

Comment: Sorry, I can't because I switched to angular 2+ since last year. But you could have a look at using a js lib directly (whyt not ace?) rather than using a thin angular wrapper that may not bring much value, it's not very difficult  and very appropriate for such a component

Comment: I would love to use the js lib directly but I am only worried how it all will work together on production profile in a jhipster project. I am not sure about the configuration in bower.json or configuration with ace.js to look for correct files as example mentioned in my question.